# Angular / Firebase / Typescript Interfaces - How to manage interface type of firebase.firestore.FieldValue with toDate()

Tags: angular, typescript, date, google-cloud-firestore, interface

I have an interface where the date is set to work with firestores timestamps.

```
    export interface Album{      
        album_name: string,
        album_date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
    }
```

If I wanted to add a new item, this works perfectly fine

```
    this.albumsCollection.add({
        album_name: "My Album",
        album_date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
     })
```

**Getting the album document from firestore**

However, upon retrieving an album **Document** from firestore, the code below will work fine if i exclude the `album_date`. However, I'm attempting to use `toDate` so that it appears in the Angular Material Date Picker

```
  public getAlbum(): Observable<Album> {
    this.itemDoc = this.afs.doc<Album>(`albums/1`);
    return this.itemDoc.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(collectionDoc => {
        const data = collectionDoc.payload.data();
        return {
          ...data,
          album_date: (data.album_date as firebase.firestore.Timestamp).toDate(),
        } as Inspection;
      }),
        shareReplay()
      );
  }
```

The error received on the line: `album_date: (data.album_date as firebase.firestore.Timestamp).toDate(),` is the following:

> Conversion of type '{ album_Date: Date; }' to type ‘Album` may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
> Types of property ‘album’_date are incompatible.
> Property 'isEqual' is missing in type 'Date' but required in type 'FieldValue'.

What's the best way to manage using 'toDate' on a returned firestore timestamp, when the interface is also configured for firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways you manage this.  Since questions seeking opinion are off-topic for Stack Overflow, you can decide for yourself which one is best for your case.

You could have two different Album interfaces, one for reading and one for writing.  The one for writing can use the FieldValue type, and the one for reading can use the Timestamp type.

You could also use [TypeScript's union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) to say that album_date can be either a FieldValue or a Timestamp.

```
album_date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue | firebase.firestore.Timestamp
```

That should allow you to cast the individual field as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks Doug! - I had to add `| Date` also to handle the `toDate` conversion for the material picker.